# Code error prestashop module php to csv

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, prestashop

```
                    if ($product['default_gold_carity'] == 14)
                            $line[$i] = $this->module->l('Set in 14k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires');
                    if ($product['default_gold_carity'] == 18)
                            $line[$i] = $this->module->l('Set in 18k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires');
                            if ($product['default_gold_carity'] == 14 && $product['price_diamond']) > 0)
                                $line[$i] = $this->module->l('Set in 14k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires with Diamonds');
                                elseif ($product['default_gold_carity'] == 18 && $product['price_diamond']) > 0)
                                $line[$i] = $this->module->l('Set in 18k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires with Diamonds');
                                    else
                                $line[$i] = $this->module->l('This is a loose stone');
```

Hi everyone.

So basically what my modules does is extract product information from mysql database and export into CSV format.

There is this table ps_product where column is default_gold_carity where value is either 14 , 18 and 0. So if value is 14 it will show "Set in 14k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires" and if 18 then it should show "Set in 18k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires"

There is one more column name "price_diamonds" where if value is more than 0 then there is a diamond and result will be "Set in 14k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires with Diamonds" or "Set in 18k Gold with Moissanite Solitaires with Diamonds"

If there is no gold at all but diamond than it should show "There is diamond"

If all the results is false it should show. "this is a loose solitaire"

Comment: In your question you need to include what your problem is, what you've done to solve it and why it didn't solve your problem. There's no question in this post.

Comment: Well my code is not executing correctly.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good description of your problem. What are the symptoms?